# Localhost address in the Virtual Machine

Tags: java, linux, networking, jmf

I am using a virtual machine on a server.
My local IP of the VM is `192.168.1.10`

I am trying to achieve something which requires me to edit my `/etc/hosts` as provided in this link

http://www.thatisjava.com/java-tech/55200/

I am having similar problems, My console reads

```
RTP--- :DataAddress: /192.168.1.10
ControlAddress: /192.168.1.10
DataPort: 42050
ControlPort: 42051
java.io.IOException: Local Data AddressDoes not belong to any of this hosts local interfaces
java.io.IOException: Local Data AddressDoes not belong to any of this hosts local interfaces
at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPConsumer.init(RTPConsumer.java:181)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPConsumer.<init>(RTPConsumer.java:95)
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.server.RTPStreamReplicator.<init>    (RTPStreamReplicator.java:69)
```

And some more.

The answer to the problem given is

> I solved this one. The problem is JMF seems to use
>   InetAddress.getAllByName() which returns (at least in my case) only
>   single IP address no matter how many addresses I have defined on my
>   interfaces. The problem was solved by placing my IP address that I
>   wanted to use by session manager into /etc/hosts. It must be the first
>   line in /etc/hosts otherwise the other row that matches is used.

Unfortunately, I cant make out what He is trying to state. My `/etc/hosts` read

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1       SparkVM104
```

So am I supposed to change `127.0.0.1` with my `192.168.1.10`

or am I supposed to create an alias like `127.0.0.1/192.168.1.10`

or Shall I just paste `192.168.1.10` in the top as

```
192.168.1.10
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1       SparkVM104
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for `/etc/hosts` is

```
IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
```

(see http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts), so to list 192.168.1.10 first, the `/etc/hosts` file would have to look like this:

```
192.168.1.10    SomeHostName    SomeOtherHostName
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Your recommendation does not agree with your citation.

Comment: The example in the citation shows `localhost` mapping to `127.0.0.1`, and the external hostname mapped to the external IP address. This is the configuration that works. Yours will not.

Comment: I re-read the man page and I didn't find a paragraph where it explicitly states that it is forbidden to use aliases for the loopback interface. It actually works on Ubuntu 11.10 and MacOS X 10.7. Nonetheless I changed the example because I see your point and would appreciate a pointer to some sort of documentation or RFC that discusses that issue. A quick Google search wasn't very successful.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/hosts, localhost should map to 127.0.0.1 and nothing else, and your external hostname to your external IP address and nothing else. Some Linux distributions are stated to violate this rule and it breaks everything.